# Credit Card Processing API

Tags: api, credit-card

I need opinion on cheapest credit card processing api, any one aware of. Also I would like to know if any service is available which let me accept credit card on form and transfer it to multiple customers’ accounts.  I mean after charging my fees I send the remaining transaction to customer account.

Comment: From the http://stackoverflow.com/tour: "Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."

Comment: My question is against specific need and I was not sure which api provides that. I worked in past with Authorize.net and I remembered we have merchant account for each of them

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Stripe Connect API](https://stripe.com/connect) to fit your needs. It is fully PCI compliant and you can allow users to make transactions with each other. You can even take an application fee per charge without without having to collect any full payments yourself. Which basically means (for example), UserA can pay UserB $20 directly, and you can charge a $1 fee for that transaction. You collect the $1 and UserB gets his $19.

Of course, though, they do charge a modest `2.9% + 30 cents` per transaction. But in my past experiences, Stripe Connect has been my favorite and easiest to implement.

Comment: Thanks . Just to confirm that I can have multiple customers e.g hotels and all can be paid through one account which I owns (correct) and I will add my account as customer e.g C so If A pay 20 dollars, B will get (20- 2.9%+.3 + My fees) and C will get 2.9%+.3+my fees.

Comment: Almost. Stripe would get the 2.9% + .30 and you would get your transaction fee. So 20 - (2.9% +.30) - your_fee would go to B. And your_fee would go to C.